# Unable to connect to remote server via SSH - "kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, remote-server

I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect to my remote server via SSH. I receive the following error message: "kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host. Connection closed by remote host port 22." Strangely, my colleagues are able to connect to the server without any problems.

What I have tried:

- Verified network connectivity: I confirmed that I have an active
  internet connection and can reach the server's IP address via ping.
- Checked SSH service status: I ensured that the SSH service (sshd) is
  running on the remote server using the command sudo systemctl status
  sshd.
- Checked firewall rules: I reviewed the firewall settings on the
  server using the command sudo iptables -L and confirmed that there
  are no explicit rules blocking incoming SSH connections.
- Verified SSH configuration: I examined the SSH configuration file
  (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) and checked that it allows remote SSH access
  (PasswordAuthentication and PubkeyAuthentication are enabled).
- Attempted to debug: To gather more information, I tried enabling the
  debug mode for the SSH daemon by modifying the LogLevel setting in
  sshd_config to DEBUG. However, I couldn't find anything significant
  indicating the cause of the problem.
- Restarted both the sshd daemon and the entire remote server
- I also scanned the Internet for potential help, also posts here on overflow, but none helped me solve the issue unfortunately

We recently switched from barracuda vpn (which it worked with) to cloudflare, as I am able to ping the server I am however in doubt that that is the reason.

Verboste connection attempt:
[image]

I'm seeking assistance in identifying the cause of this issue and finding a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?